# Closure of $\bigcup\limits_1^\infty(\frac{1}{n+1}, \frac{1}{n})$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

If $E:=\bigcup\limits_1^\infty(\frac{1}{n+1}, \frac{1}{n})$ in $\mathbb{R}$, then its interior is open, since a union of open sets is open, thus $E^\circ=E$, since $E^\circ$ is the largest open set contained in $E$.

Now, for the closure of $E$, one might consider $\bar{E}:=\bigcup\limits_1^\infty[\frac{1}{n+1}, \frac{1}{n}]=[\frac{1}{n+1}, \frac{1}{n}]$. However, I don't think that $E$ has a closure because, then, what will $\bar{E}\backslash E^\circ$ be? I don't think that this set has either closure or boundary.

I would appreciate some hints.

Comment: What do you mean by $\{\frac 1 {n+1}, \frac 1 n\}$? This is a set with two elements, not an interval.

Comment: Do you really mean that $E$ is the union of the open intervals $(1/(n+1),1/n)$? If so your notation using the curly brackets is not standard for this.

Comment: Also in the closure, the points $1/k$ get included and it winds up $[0,\infty)$ so it does have a closure.

Comment: Once again: **every set has an interior**, and **every set has a closure**. **The empty set exists.** ("Once again" because in your other question  you said you thought the interior of some set "doesn't exist", but you meant $= \emptyset$.) Write on the blackboard 100x: "$\exists x\, x=\emptyset$".

Comment: @BrianO: sorry, just made the correction.

Comment: Does every neighborhood of $0$ intersect $E$?

Comment: If $D:= \{x: x < 0\}$ then $D\cap E = \emptyset$.

Comment: Is $D$ a neighborhood of $0$? Why mention it?

Comment: $D$ includes part of the neighbourhood of $0$ which is not in $E$.

Comment: So what. $D$ is not a neighborhood of $0$.

Comment: @hermes Yes $n>0$, but that's the least of our worries.

Comment: The first equality is correct: $\overline{E}$ does equal that union of closed intervals (BUT with n starting at $1$ not $0$). But then a few incorrect conclusions follow. $E\subseteq [0,1]$ so $\overline{E}\subseteq [0,1]$.  The boundary doesn't equal the closure. In fact the closure is $[0,1]$.

Comment: $B_{\epsilon}(x)$ = {y| |x - y| < $\epsilon$} .  If x = 0 and our space is $\mathbb R$ then B = {y| |y| < $\epsilon$} = (-$\epsilon, \epsilon$) .  Now (-$\epsilon$, 0) don't have any points of E so fuck it.  But what about [0, -$\epsilon$)?  Does it have any points of E?  Does it have any 1/k?  Does it *always*?

Comment: " It thus comes intuitively that $\bar{E}:=\bigcup\limits_0^\infty[\frac{1}{n+1}, \frac{1}{n}]=[0, \infty)$."  Really????  If $x > 1$ is $x$ in either the closure of E or the union of closed intervals?  Intuitive is actually incorrect because (hint) is 0 in any of the closed intervals?  But, seriously? Your intuition says 2, 27, and 5,679.72 is in one of the intervals?

Comment: The lower index should be $1$, not $0$, hence was my mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some minor points: You probably meant $\bigcup_1^{\infty}(1/(n+1),1/n)$ since $1/n$ is undefined for $n=0$.

Anyway, what does your intuition tell you about this set $E$?

Hopefully it's not too hard to see that

$$
E=(0,1)\setminus\{1/n:n\ge2\}
$$

Once you can see this, only thing that you have to do is to prove the equality. To do that, you have to do two things:

1. Show that $x\in E \implies x\in G:=(0,1)\setminus\{1/n:n\ge2\}$
2. Show that $x\in G \implies x\in E$ (this is converse of 1)

I'll do 1. for you. It is clear that if $x\in E$ then $x\in (0,1)$ since $x$ is in one of $(1/(n+1), 1/n)$. But it's also clear that $x\neq 1/n$ for any $n\ge 2$. So in fact $x\in G$.

For 2. note that if $x\in G$ then $x\in (0,1)$ and $x\neq 1/n$ for any $n\ge 2$. Now you just have two show that $x$ lies in at least one of the intervals of the form $(1/(n+1),1/n)$

After this, hopefully you can see what closure of $E$ is.

Comment: I've made the correction. It's indeed from $1$ to $\infty$.

Comment: You might want to correct the title too.

Answer (score 2):

$E=(0,1)\setminus \{1/n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$. Hence its closure is $[0,1]$. (Why?)

Comment: Why is $\{1/n:n\ge2\}$ excluded?

Comment: Seriously? Are any of the points $1/n$ in $E$?

Comment: $E$ is defined over $\mathbb{R}$, so why not?

Comment: I give up. Read the definition of $E$, will ya? You wrote it.

Comment: $E:=\bigcup\limits_1^\infty(\frac{1}{n+1}, \frac{1}{n})$ in $\mathbb{R}$, not in $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Again, so what. $E$ contains no integers. How can it contain any reciprocal of an integer, given that all the intervals are open, etc.

Comment: OK, I got it. I'm pretty new to topology, so I don't have much prior experience with open and closed sets and their unions and intersections. Now I wrote it some parts of this union on paper and everything is much clearer now.

Comment: Why are you taking a course in it?

Comment: This is some basic topology which is only a relatively small part of an introductory course in real analysis.

Comment: Let $m$ be a positive integer.  If $n > m$ then $1/n < 1/m$ and $1/m \not \in (\frac 1 {n + 1}, 1/n)$.  If $n = m$ then  $1/m \not \in (\frac 1 {n + 1}, 1/n)$.  If $n < m$ then $1/m \le 1/(n+ 1)$ then $1/m \not \in (\frac 1 {n + 1}, 1/n)$  So $1/m \not \in \cup (1/(n+1), 1/n) = E$.

Comment: *Visualize* E: it is ...(1/100,1/99)(1/99, 1/98)......(1/3,1/2)(1/2,1).  It's basically all the points in 0 to 1 *except* 1/n. for all n.

Answer (score 0):

$\bullet $Every subset $A$ of a topological space $S$ has a closure. The definition of the closure of $A$ is the intersection of all closed sets that have $A$ as a subset. That is, $\bar A=\cap F$ where $F=\{B\subset S : B$ is closed $\}.$ Note that 1:  $\;F \ne \phi$ because $S\in F$.... 2: $\;A\subset \bar A$.... 3: $\;\bar A$ is closed, because it is the common intersection of the family $F$ of closed sets.... 3: If $C$ is a closed set with$ A\subset C$ then $\bar A\subset C$.... 4: If $A_1\subset A_2$ then $\bar A_1\subset \bar A_2$.... and 5: $\;\overline {A_1\cup A_2}=\bar A_1 \cup \bar A_2.\quad$ $\bullet$Every subset $A$ of a topological space $S$ has a boundary. The definition of the boundary of $A$  is $\partial A=\bar A \cap \overline {S\backslash A}.$